# min and max width don't work

Tags: html, css

i'm creating a horizontal submenu but the width doesn't extend check this please

### CSS

```
nav{
    width:62px;
    height:409px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:25px;    
}
nav a:link,nav a:visited{
    width:59px;
    height:67px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:19px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:9px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:62px;
    text-align:center;  
}
nav .menu{
    width:59px;
    height:67px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;  
    margin-bottom:19px;
}
nav .submenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:59px;
    background:#f78f1e;
    height:40px;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
nav .submenu a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:50px;
}

HTMLnav{
    width:62px;
    height:409px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:25px;    
}
nav a:link,nav a:visited{
    width:59px;
    height:67px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:#ccc;
    margin-bottom:19px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:9px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:62px;
    text-align:center;  
}
nav .menu{
    width:59px;
    height:67px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;  
    margin-bottom:19px;
}
nav .submenu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:59px;
    background:#f78f1e;
    height:40px;
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
nav .submenu a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:50px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<nav>
<a href="#">contact</a>
<a href="#">works</a>
<a href="#">partners</a>
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">about us</a>
<div class="submenu">
  <a href="#">audio</a>
  <a href="#">video</a>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#">services</a>
</nav>
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7D9hV/

Comment: what does "doesn't extend" mean? What are your expected results?

Comment: there's another link "video" is not showing up next to "audio"

Comment: the "video" link should be next to "audio" link horizontally

Comment: yes it's absolute but elements are float left can it be done using css or should i use jquery?

Comment: You can wrap elements in a div absolutely positioned and then just let them float inside it with static position or relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me. Try it

```
nav .submenu a {
    background: inherit;  /// remove 'none'
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}

nav .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 59px;
    background: #f78f1e;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;    // assign width
    min-width: 20px;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: just a little help to make the submenu behind the nav code updated

Answer (score 1):

Try using `backgournd:inherit` for your anchor-styling

```
nav .submenu a{
background:inherit;
display:block;
float:left;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
width:50px;
}
```

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, scratch previous comment. It's the `background: none;` on `nav .submenu a`. Remove this and they appear. Your setting the background to `none` so you can't see them as the text is white:

http://jsfiddle.net/7D9hV/7/

Comment: still the same width is not expanding

Comment: What does expanding mean?